# keepalived service is not down despite I turned it down

Tags: linux, high-availability, keepalived

For high availability I have two servers: 172.24.4.51 and 172.24.4.52 and virutal ip is 172.24.4.53. The master is 172.24.4.51 and backup is 172.24.4.52.
I'm on 172.24.4.51 and then I made systemctl stop keepalived but keepalived services is still alived on that server. I made kill -9 to keepalived's process but then these process are recreated again automatically. And I made systemctl staus keepalived and the status shows Loaded: loadeded, Active: inactive but it keeps alived. I made ip a and I see the virtual ip active.

I'm giving you keepalived configuration

What could it be happening?

```
vrrp_script chk_haproxy {
   script "killall -0 haproxy"   # verify the pid existance
   interval 2                    # check every 2 seconds
   weight 2                      # add 2 points of prio if OK
}

vrrp_instance VI_1 {
   interface ens192              # interface to monitor
   state MASTER
   virtual_router_id 51          # Assign one ID for this route
   priority 101                   # 101 on master, 100 on backup
   unicast_src_ip 172.24.4.51
   unicast_peer {
       172.24.4.52  
   }
   virtual_ipaddress {
       172.24.4.53                        # the virtual IP
   }
   track_script {
       chk_haproxy
   }

   notify_master /etc/keepalived/master.sh
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check master.sh content, actually keepalived try to make primary node as master only if server is reachable and don't have any issue with keepalived config, I think in your case whenever you are trying to stop/kill may be restarted by config management tool/monit or from some other script.

Also please check the transition logs.